# Why aren't defective words perfected?

Tags: english, french

Since Académie française superintends French, a solution seems easier (at least to prescribe and enforce) in French; I exemplify with it. Yet I question the same for  [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_verb).

Why hasn't French confected* conjugations or words that cause the defect, for want of efficiency? For example, I remain shocked that [*« frire »*](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/FRverbs.aspx?v=frire) still lacks conjugations that are wholly logical and necessary in modern use; we, [ye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction) , and they still fry Fries. Instead, [one must capitulate to *« faire frire »*](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/FRverbs.aspx?v=frire), unproductively.

*Footnote: Pun was intended and found thanks to www.wordfind.com/ends-with/fect/.

Comment: Because this is not the way language works. The official bodies have nothing to do with it. Even if you publish the correct words to use, if nobody pays any attention you really can't do anything about it. It's kind of like telling teenagers not to have sex. The speakers know what they're doing because they keep doing it, even if they can't articulate what it is they're doing. Why hasn't English "confected" the defective verb _be named_ into a active transitive one like German _heissen_, for instance? And what's the past tense of _Beware_?

Comment: In (my wholly subjective experience of) actual practice in French, the verb _frire_ simply isn't used as a finite verb very much, and isn't conjugated very much. The infinitive collocates with _faire_, or _à_, while the past participle is the only other form in common use, mainly as an attributive adjective.

Comment: @jlawler Thanks for your comment. What about 'hight' for English? See http://english.stackexchange.com/a/28777. I haven't found an answer to the `past tense of Beware`, but I never thought about this before!

Answer (score 1):

I think this has something to do with different traditions associated with a language, i.e. the different traditions of the people who maintain the language's prescriptive standards.

In some cases, "gaps" are considered valuable features of a language's uniqueness, whereas in other cases, more value is placed on logical completeness. In the case of French (or at least this particular verb), the first option seems to have won out over the second.

(Just to be clear, this is not an explanation of why gaps exist in the first place, but rather of why a gap would be maintained by prescriptive authorities rather than "filled in".  Gaps are probably originally caused by factors such as semantic likelihood and usage frequencies.)

Comment: One other thing: I highly doubt that the gap in question has never been "filled in" in people's day-to-day speech, i.e., that no French speaker have ever come up with a conjugation of *frire* in a conversation or other informal context. As far as I can see, the "defectiveness" of *frire* (and perhaps most other "defective" words) is more a question of prescriptive acceptance than of observable usage.

Comment: I'm not a Frenchman, so I wouldn't know, but many gaps persist in everyday usage, and even when they are filled in, it is done with the same awkwardness that people show when they use very complicated or unusual constructions etc., which makes it clear that they are even by them considered forms that are made up ad hoc.

Comment: Apparent awkwardness may simply be provoked by awareness of prescriptive standards. For example, if a French-speaker finds himself conjugating *frire* in the 1pl. in the middle of a conversation (e.g. *”Nous frisons”*), he may sound hesitant because he suddenly remembers having been taught that *frire* ”shouldn't” be conjugated in the 1pl., or because he realizes that he's never seen *frire* conjugated in the 1pl. in any respected written source (such as newspapers).

Comment: Again, my knowledge of French is basically nil, but if it is like most other languages, a speaker will be constantly using words or forms he has never seen in respected written sources, and probably quite a couple which he has been taught not to use.

Comment: In my day-to-day speech, I sometimes use *they* as an impersonal pronoun, even though prescriptivism explicitly says not to do so, but this kind of behavior is reinforced by frequency: for semantic reasons, I probably have far more opportunities to use impersonal pronouns than to use the verb "fry" in one of the plural persons. Frequency probably helps to erode the ”awkwardness” that might otherwise arise (and probably does arise for some people regardless) when using *they* in this way.

Comment: Yes, but you would be able to use the past simple of "correspond" or "invalidate" instantly and without awkwardness, even though you probably don't read it all that often. If that isn't the case with the plural of "frire", then there is a gap. Also, I presume that there are a lot of French people who never formally learned that there is no plural of "frire". If they still don't use it, then there is a real gap. If they do use it, the gap is due to prescriptiveness. My point is only that there are gaps also in modes of speech that aren't officially regulated.

Comment: @user8017 prescriptivism rarely has much to do with reality. Defective verbs tend to actually be grounded in reality as no one uses them. *can* is defective in English but prescriptivists don't mention you can't say *to can* or *I will can* because its defectiveness is simply known (naturally) to all native speakers. But looking to Spanish, we can see that some defective verbs over time may fill out their forms (like abolir) after people start using them (perhaps due to old cacophony not being so cacophonous). I don't think it's a tradition vs logic, it's people using what sounds right to them

Comment: @guifa I don't accept that the defectiveness of words such as *can* is naturally known by English speakers. I don't personally recall hearing anyone say "to can", but that doesn't mean that no first-language English speaker has ever uttered this form, or even that no one does so habitually -- there are a lot of English-speakers in the world right now, and it can be dangerous to make universal assumptions about what "always" or "never" happens in their speech.

Comment: @guifa Also, the fact that many English speakers (such as myself) don't normally say "to can" doesn't automatically prove that prescriptive pressure has no effect on so-called defective words. For example, how often in practice does the opportunity come up to say "to be able to" / "to can"? If such opportunities are below a certain threshold of frequency, then there is probably less "momentum of regularity", and therefore less likelihood for us to choose a form like "to can" instead of reverting to what we remember hearing in the past and/or what has been explicitly prescribed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the Académie Française sees it as her mission to keep the language "pure", not to invent new and useful words. They just aren't concerned with adding stuff. (But maybe, if you make it popular enough to use an English loanword for 'faire frire', the Académie will invent a new way of doing it).